# __NSCFDictionary length unrecognized selector sent to NSJSONSerialied NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I make a JSON request with NSURLConnection, I get an "unrecognized selector" error [__NSCFDictionary length].

We changed from sending the request in the header as a UTF8String where it worked,  to the body which requires NSData for some reason. We made that change because there will eventually be too much data for the header.

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it? Is this somehow a problem with the object in memory? I'm baffled.

```
    -(void)initWebserviceWithJSONRequest:(NSData *)jsonRequest url:(NSURL *)url
    {
       //initialize the responseData property //
       self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
       NSError *error = nil;
       NSMutableData *requestData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
       requestData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonRequest options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
       // create the URL request that will be passed to the NSURLConnection class // 
       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

       // set up the request values //
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       // line below included to show that there is a length available for requestData
       int jsonLength = requestData.description.length;// This works because it's .description.length
       [request setHTTPBody:requestData ];

       // Make a connection //
       self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
```

The call to this method is like this:

```
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [service createWebserviceWithJSONRequest:jsonData url:loginURL];
```

And here is the json that I'm sending in the body:

```
    {
        CURRENTDATETIME = "2012-11-16 18:11:26";
        CURRENTUSERTOKEN = "";
        REQUESTDATA = "{\"USERNAME\":\"testUserName\", \"PASSWORD\":\"TestPassword\", \"APPVERSION\":\"0.001.1\", \"CARRIER\":\"ATT\", \"DEVICENAME\":\"iPad Simulator\", \"DEVICETOKEN\":\"9A384B42-7766-55AE-B61D-0AAB74A4304B\", \"OSVERSION\":\"5.1\", \"LATITUDE\":10.72182, \"LONGITUDE\":-10.148127, \"ISWIFI\":\"true\", \"BATTERYLEVEL\":42.2, \"SCREENHEIGHT\":1024, \"SCREENWIDTH\":768, \"SCREENPPI\":132, \"SIGNALSTRENGTH\":4, \"APPPACKAGE\":1003}";
        TRANSACTIONDATETIME = "2012-11-16 18:11:26";
        TRANSACTIONUSERTOKEN = "";
    }
```

NOTE
I'm using xcode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002)

And iOS Simulator Version 5.1 (272.21)

On Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Note - you can use Xcode 4.5.x with the iPad 1. The version of Xcode is irrelevant. What matters is the Deployment Target setting for your app.

Comment: You're sending a dictionary where you probably should be sending an NSData.

Comment: Your "requestData" isn't an NSMutableData.  You're using the wrong JSON converter direction.

Comment: (In fact, it looks pretty generally bolloxed up.  You should be passing an dictionary/array into your method, I suspect.)

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for pointing that out. I removed that comment.

Comment: @HotLicks, I'm not sure what you mean when you say I'm sending a dictionary. It really looks like NSMutableData to me. What do you mean when you say requestData isn't NSMutableData? I have put this together as plain NSData and that didn't change anything. I have tried passing a dictionary into this method and making NSData from it. That 'works' as in I don't have this error. However, I also don't appear to have UTF8String serialized data going to the server which is what they are expecting. I've also tried this JSON request using a RESTClient and it works fine. Please clarify.

Comment: I mean that the message says you're sending a dictionary.  And JSONObjectWithData returns a dictionary or array, so this is to be expected.  Just because the variable has a type does not mean it IS that type in a "duck typed" language like Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when sending data via JSON, you've got some relatively complex structure in the phone (or whatever) that you want to convert to a JSON string for transmission.

JSON strings "map" pretty well to NSDictionaries and NSArrays, so the presumption is that you get your data on the phone side into a structure of NSDictionaries and NSArrays and then pass the "root" dictionary/array to `dataWithJSONObject` (or, better, a different brand of JSON parser/serializer).  The Apple API will return an NSData object from that conversion which can either be sent directly or converted to an NSString and sent, depending on the network interface you use.

When/if you get JSON data back you send it through `JSONObjectWithData` to convert into a "nest" of NSArrays and NSDictionaries that your app can understand.

You've got your inputs and outputs reversed.

Comment: You are correct when you say I have my outputs reversed. I should have had dataWithJSONObject:jsonRequest. I've made that change but I still have problems with it. It creates hexadecimal data. Changed the method signature to: -(void)createWebserviceWithJSONRequest:(NSDictionary *)jsonRequest url:(NSURL *)url and NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonRequest options:0 error:&error ]; and [request setHTTPBody:requestData]; No joy.

Comment: No, it doesn't create hexadecimal data.  You're dumping an NSData object and they're dumped in hex -- it's still basically ASCII data.  (This is the main reason I hate the NSJSONSerialization API -- it doesn't produce an NSString.)

Comment: I went ahead and marked your question as the answer. Since what you suggested solved the hard error I described. Thanks for you help thus far. Any other ideas? The server doesn't like the response this way- although the JSON works in WizTools.org RESTClient 2.4.

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong between client and server.  Ideally you have someone on the other end who can tell you what the server's objecting to, or you're getting detailed diagnostics back.  If not, it's trial and error, and a bit of thinking hard about what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

```
requestData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonRequest options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

is wrong, since `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` won't return a `NSData`.

The returned type depends on what's contained in your `jsonRequest` (it could be a `NSDictionary`, a `NSArray` or whatever...).

The question now is: why don't you simply pass the `jsonRequest` object to the `setHTTPBody` method?

Comment: I tried simply using jsonRequest and I get the same error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcc85dd0'

Comment: May be the reason I'm having trouble is the way I'm creating the NSData object: NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  I updated the example code with this.

Comment: Apple confuses the heck out of things by requiring that the string side of the JSON conversion ops be an NSData rather than an NSString.